# How to set black status bar with a background image in iPhone X?

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar

App has an yellow image as a background, and status bar is set hidden,  it works well on other devices except iPhone X.

The status bar sticks on white text color.

[image]

I tried to add the following code, still failed:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle{
  return .default      
}
```

Any other suggestion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1:**

You have to add this value to plist: "**View controller-based status bar appearance**" and set it to "**NO**".

After that add this in `AppDelegate`

```
   var window: UIWindow?
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            if (window?.safeAreaInsets.top)! > CGFloat(0.0) || window?.safeAreaInsets != .zero {
                print("iPhone X")
                application.isStatusBarHidden = true
                //or UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true
            }
            else {
                print("Not iPhone X")
                application.isStatusBarHidden = true
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```

**Method 2:**
"**View controller-based status bar appearance**" and set it to "**YES**". *Which is by default.*

As in iOS11+ `setStatusBarHidden` & `isStatusBarHidden` are deprecated, 
[prefersStatusBarHidden][2] is available from iOS7+, We can make status bar visibility settings over `ViewController` as-

```
struct StatusBarInfo {
    static var isToHiddenStatus = false
  }
    var window: UIWindow?
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            if (window?.safeAreaInsets.top)! > CGFloat(0.0) || window?.safeAreaInsets != .zero {
                print("iPhone X")
                StatusBarInfo.isToHiddenStatus = true
            }
            else {
                StatusBarInfo.isToHiddenStatus = true
                print("Not iPhone X")
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```

**In ViewController.Swift**

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return StatusBarInfo.isToHiddenStatus
    }
```

Comment: Thanks you suggestion. I use the method 1, the status bar is hidden. How can I make it black text color if I want it shows on iPhone X?

Comment: Welcome !!! @jdleung kindly use this code
                             `UIApplication.shared.setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.default, animated: true)`

this is for black color status bar

Comment: `UIApplication.shared.setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.lightcontent, animated: true)` this is for white color status bar